# How to extract only the header name in a data without listing the data itself

Tags: linux, text-processing

I have a data set that has 1127 columns, I only need to know the header without listing the data itself in each column.

For example, data as

```
name age
m     33
A     26
```

I need a code in UNIX that will give me the header, which in this case is: name, age.

Comment: [How to print the the first line...](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/294486) sure, that guy was trying to do it with grep but anyway, the answers there should work for you too...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Using [head](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/head.html)

```
head -n 1 filename
# OR
cat filename | head -n 1
```

### Using [Sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)

```
sed 1q filename
# OR
sed -n 1p filename
# OR
cat filename | sed 1q
```

### Using [Awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)

```
awk NR==1 filename
# OR
cat filename | awk 'NR==1'
```

### Using [ex](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html)

```
ex -sc '1p|q' filename
```

### Using [more](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/more.html)

```
more -n2 -pq filename
# OR
cat filename | more -n2 -pq
```

---

## Notes

In all of the above commands, `cat filename |`  is intended as a stand-in for any command that produces textual output, showing how to use these tools in a pipeline.

All commands use only features listed in [POSIX Specifications](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).