# How to delete everything after the 5th line with awk?

Tags: awk, gawk

How to delete everything in a file after 5th line using awk?

I can do it by sed, but these days I am moving from sed to awk.

Comment: Have you seen awk's NR variable?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/322171/135943

Comment: You can't say "I'm moving to `awk`".  That would be like saying "I'm starting to see the benefits of a hammer over a screwdriver. I think I'll be using the hammer from now on." It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

`awk 'NR <= 5' inputfile` would do it (it prints whenever NR, the record number, is less than or equal to five.

Comment: You misread the question; should be `awk 'NR <= 5'`.  And you don't need to call `print` explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'NR > 5{exit}1' yourfile
```

would quit "awk" as soon as the 6th line is reached. But prior to that, the default action would apply, thereby printing lines 1..5.