# How do you slice in shell?

Tags: shell

for example:

Let say this is a file num

```
1.   hi
2.   hello
3.   hey
```

How do I remove the white spaces to just get the hello?

```
$ head -1 num | (what should be here to make it below)
hi
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print the the first line using grep comand?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294486/how-to-print-the-the-first-line-using-grep-comand)

Comment: No, I'm trying to format white spaces out. i.e the 1.   hi -> hi

Comment: `awk '{NR==1; print $2; exit}' file`

Comment: If you removed just the spaces you'd have `1.hi`. Please clarify _in your question_ what you really mean.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` uses code built like patterns with actions.  The "pattern" that you have here is that you'd like to do something with the first line only, and the "action" is "print the second column (and then quit)":

```
awk 'NR == 1 { print $2; exit }' file
```

The `exit` is an optional optimization in this case and could be removed (there is no other line for which `NR` would be 1). `NR` means "the ordinal number of the current line" or "the number of lines read so far".

---

In this simple case, building from your `head` attempt:

```
head -n 1 file | while read -r num word; do printf '%s\n' "$word"; done
```

Alternatively,

```
read -r num word <file
printf '%s\n' "$word"
```

would accomplish the same thing as we're only interested in the first line.

... but [parsing text in the shell itself is error-prone and should be avoided](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice). With a small example like this, it would work ok though.

---

You used the word *slice* in the title, which in English has the same meaning as *cut*, which is another Unix utility. It could be used here, but it's a bit simplistic and how you use it depends on the delimiter character(s) between the two columns of data.

1. If you have a single tab between the columns:

   ```
   head -n 1 file | cut -f 2
   ```
2. If you have three spaces between the columns:

   ```
   head -n 1 file | cut -d ' ' -f 4
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether you want the first line or a specific line (`foo` is your file).

If you just want to split a specific line, use

```
$ awk 'NR==1 { print $2; exit}' foo
hi
$ awk 'NR==2 { print $2; exit}' foo
hello
```

If you want to select the line based on content, use

```
$ awk '/1./ { print $2; exit }' foo
hi
$ awk '/2./ { print $2; exit }' foo
hello
$ awk '$1 ~ 2. { print $2; exit }' foo
hello
$ awk '/hello/ { print $2; exit }' foo
hello
```

In all cases, the `exit` ensures that only the first match gets printed (and it also prevents the processing of the whole file).